# No peer certificate in Android while accessing the HTTPS URL

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I'm using HTTPClient to access the HTTPS URL. I got some SSL error like No peer certificate. I pasted my code here.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://myURL.com");
HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
```

Comment: look at this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172000/964741

Comment: if it works up vote that answer..