# Android REST API

Tags: android, rest, https

I need to access this url and put user name and password I am trying a HTTP Post request with parameter but it's giving an error.Can any one help me how can I access this url from android.

```
https://54.204.193.209:943/rest/GetUserlogin
```

Getting ERROR

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

Comment: please post your code , errors(logcat) here.

Comment: is above url remotly hosted?asking for username and password

Comment: if you are going to give username and password it's returning proper result

Comment: So.. what's the problem?

Comment: question updated with error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safely fixing: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18210464/3492139  Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

When I tried to access your url, pop up comes up asking to enter credentials that means at server side, HTTP Basic Authentication has been enabled. 
To access anything on server, you have to go through it. Add following code :

```
// Set credentials for HTTP Basic Authentication
defaultHttpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                HTTPS_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME,
                HTTPS_BASIC_AUTH_PASWORD));
```

Credentials for HTTP basic auth is unique for one server, hence you can hardcode it in your java code.
Hope, this will help you.