# Connecting to https result in exception, SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get data by calling a api from my aynctask class. When I used http for api, then worked fine but when I added **https** for the api and it then gives me couple of exceptions.

Implementation will be as shown below, can anyone figure where I have gone wrong. If I need to add more description please ask me.

**fragment class**

```
new PizzaMenuAsyncTask(getActivity(), new OnTaskCompleted() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {
                        loadMenuItems();
                    }
                }).execute();
```

**PizzaMenuAsyncTask class**

```
   public class PizzaMenuAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {
    private OnTaskCompleted listener;
    private JSONArray responseJson = null;
    private Context contxt;
    private Activity activity;
    String email;

    public PizzaMenuAsyncTask(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {

        // API = apiURL;
        this.contxt = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // async task to accept string array from context array
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        String path = null;
        String response = null;
        HashMap<String, String> request = null;
        JSONObject requestJson = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = null;
        StringEntity requestString = null;
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = null;


        try {
                        path = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ItemService.svc/ProductDetails";

            new URL(path);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            // set the API request
            request = new HashMap<String, String>();
            request.put(new String("CetegoryCode"), "PIZ");
            request.entrySet().iterator();

            // Store locations in JSON
            requestJson = new JSONObject(request);
            DefaultHttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();  // new MyHttpClient(contxt);
            httpPost = new HttpPost(path);
            requestString = new StringEntity(requestJson.toString());

            // sets the post request as the resulting string
            httpPost.setEntity(requestString);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // Handles the response
            responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response = client.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            responseJson = new JSONArray(response);
            // System.out.println("*****JARRAY*****" + responseJson.length());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return responseJson;

    }

    public DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (responseJson != null) {
            listener.onTaskCompleted(responseJson);
        }
    }

}
```

This gives me below shown exception,

```
09-15 13:08:41.998: E/Buffer Error(7848): Error converting result javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x52a04c28: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer


09-15 13:08:42.708: E/Buffer Error(7848): Error converting result javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

I followed this tutorial as well still it gives above mentioned exception.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL

Comment: No peer certificate....seems as if the server does not have a signed certificate installed on it.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Can u suggest me how to install the certificate on it? is it same as the url I have posted in the question?

Comment: May i know which server are you using ?

Comment: its rackspace server. ios connected without any trouble but android gives me this exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate , look here

Comment: ios can access it without any issue. problem is only with android. Even fidler gives output