# error javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate and SSLNullSession.java:104

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I'm facing this error `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate on android version lower than Marshmallow` when I use https to connect the server and I'm getting this exception:

```
   03-27 16:15:04.481 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
   03-27 16:15:04.495 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.intellinects.app.Network.executeService(Network.java:77)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.intellinects.app.Network.checkSecureConnection(Network.java:180)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.intellinects.app.Network.get(Network.java:124)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.intellinects.app.SplashActivity$CheckURL.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:144)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at com.intellinects.app.SplashActivity$CheckURL.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:127)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
   03-27 16:15:04.496 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   03-27 16:15:04.497 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   03-27 16:15:04.497 23391-23469/com.intellinects.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Just fixed some English typos and escape some inlined code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server you connected to doesn't have a great SSL certificate. A quick search to StackOverflow forwarded me to this great question and answers: [Safely fixing: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate)

Comment: I have trusted Comodo certificate and my app is working perfectly for marshmallow version. Facing issue for lollipop version.

Comment: Have you tried to access that URL via SSL on your common browser? Don't know why, some certificates doesn't work on Android. We had a bad experience with RapidSSL ones, for example :·/

Answer (score 0):

The server you are trying to connect is not authorized. You will have to do SSL pinning, download the SSL Certificate signed by any CA.