# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer Certificate [Android]

Tags: java, android, ssl, exception, tls1.2

I'm using the following code to Verify `Certificate Chain, Expiry Date, Domain Name, Trusted CA and Principal Signature` of the server.

```
       SSLContext sslContext = CustomSSLContext.getSSLContext(mContext);
                        SSLSocketFactory factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
                        NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket= (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(businessIp, businessPort);
                        NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
                        NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().
                                getSupportedCipherSuites());
                        NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.setUseClientMode(true);
 NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(
                                new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
                                    public void handshakeCompleted(
                                            HandshakeCompletedEvent event) {
                                        try {
                                            Certificate[] chain = NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
                                            X509Certificate subject = (X509Certificate)  chain[0];
                                            X509Certificate issuer = (X509Certificate)  chain[1];
                                            X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate)  chain[2];
                                            Date certifcateExpiryDate = neml.getNotAfter();
                                            // Next Steps :- Verify Certificate Chain, Expiry Date, Domain Name, Trusted CA and Principal Signature
                                                      .
                                                      .
                                                      .
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Logger.log(e);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                        );
                        NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.startHandshake();
```

I can assure that the code works fine for the most part, it connects to the server and perform all the validation on completion of the `handshake` but the problem arises when I exit from my app and try to open the app again to create a new `Socket` connection and perform the `handshake`.

```
NetworkUtils.mSSLPrimarySocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
```

The above line inside the Handshake completed listener throws the following exception :-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer Certificate
```

Comment: check this out-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126372/safely-fixing-javax-net-ssl-sslpeerunverifiedexception-no-peer-certificate

Comment: This link is irrelevant as I am using TCP SSLSocket to establish a connection with the server and it fails only when I exit my application and tries to reestablish the TCP Connection.

Comment: Don't enable all the supported cipher suites. That will add all the non-authenticating ones, which are insecure, and allow the server to not present a certificate, which is your problem. NB You don't need to verify the certificate chain or expiries yourself. JSSE already does all that.